# Sandwich rule for continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $c ∈ X ⊆ R $ . Suppose that $f : X → \mathbb{R}$, $g : X → \mathbb{R}$, and $h : X → \mathbb{R}$ are functions such that $g(x) ≤ f(x) ≤ h(x)$ for all $x ∈ X$.

Suppose that $g$ and $h$ is continuous at $c$ and $g(c) = h(c).$

Question: Show that f is continuous at c.

Attempt:

I have started by writing down the following.

Let $\epsilon >0$. We know that $g$ is continuous hence we have $\delta_g$ such that

$|x-c|< \delta_g$ $\implies$ $|g(x)-g(c)|< \epsilon$.

We know that $h$ is continuous hence we have $\delta_h$ such that

$|x-c|< \delta_h$ $\implies$ $|h(x)-h(c)|< \epsilon$.

How do I connect $f$ to $h$ and $g$?

Comment: Start by writing the condition for continuity correctly: You have a $\delta_g > 0$ such that $|g(x)-g(c)|< \epsilon$ for all $x$ with $|x-c|< \delta_g$ ...

Comment: And how does it relate to f?

Comment: You have $f(c)=g(c)=h(c)$ by assumption.

Comment: Would it then suffice to write:

We have the $g(c) = h(c)$,  by assumption from the inequality, we obtain $f(c) = g(c) = h(c)$. Hence, $f$ is continuous at $c$ as $g(c)$ and $h(c)$ are continous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that setting $x=c$ in the inequality implies that $g(c) \le f(c) \le h(c) = g(c)$ and therefore $g(c) = f(c) = h(c)$.

For $\epsilon > 0$ you have found $\delta_g > 0$ and $\delta_h > 0$ such that
$$
|x-c|< \delta_g \implies |g(x)-g(c)| < \epsilon \implies g(x) > g(c) - \epsilon\\
|x-c|< \delta_h \implies  |h(x)-h(c)| < \epsilon \implies h(x) < h(c) + \epsilon
$$
Now set $\delta = \min(\delta_g, \delta_h)$. Then $|x-c| < \delta$ implies
$$
 f(c) - \epsilon = g(c) - \epsilon <  g(x) \le f(x)
$$
and
$$
 f(x) \le h(x) < h(c) + \epsilon =  f(c) + \epsilon 
$$
and therefore
$$
 f(c) - \epsilon < f(x) <  f(c) + \epsilon \iff |f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon \, .
$$

Comment: As long as you have not proven that $f(c)=g(c)=h(c)$, your first inequalities are not justified.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Better now?

Comment: That's perfect ! ;-)

Comment: I don't quite follow the reasoning behind setting $\delta$ = min($\delta_g$, $\delta_h$), and also how we got $f(c) - \epsilon$ $\leq$ $g(x)$ $\leq$ $f(x)$ and $f(x)$ $\leq$ $h(x)$ $\leq$ $f(c)$ + $\epsilon$

Comment: @Car: You set $\delta = \min(\delta_g, \delta_h)$ so that for $|x-c| < \delta$ *both* of the preceding inequalities are satisfied. – Note that $|g(x)-g(c)| < \epsilon$ is equivalent to $g(c)-\epsilon < g(x)  < g(c)+\epsilon$, similarly for $h$.

Comment: but why do we set $\delta$ = min($\delta_g$, $\delta_h$) instead of max?

Comment: @Car: We need that $|x-c| <\delta_g$ **and** $|x-c| <\delta_h$, that is equivalent to $|x-c| < \min(\delta_g, \delta_h)$.

Comment: Oh right, I get it now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the sandwich theorem for limits is allowed. So by this theorem,

$$\lim_{x\to c}g(x)\le\lim_{x\to c}f(x)\le\lim_{x\to c}h(x).$$

In addition, by continuity of $g$ and $h$,

$$\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=g(c),\\\lim_{x\to c}h(x)=h(c).$$

Hence

$$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=f(c)=g(c)=h(c)$$ QED.

---

Note that continuity of $g$ and $h$ is required, otherwise you could very well have

$$\lim_{x\to c}g(x)\ne g(c)\text{ and }\lim_{x\to c}h(x)\ne h(c).$$